# How do I create this page flip effect in CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to replicate the page-turning effect on [turnjs.com](http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs/40)

The Github page seems last updated 11 years ago so it's not using some niche javascript that's only available in cutting edge browsers, and it's not using SVG paths or Canvas. (I just ctrl+f searched on https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/blob/master/turn.js)

I was able to code the [dynamic degree where the next page shows](https://codepen.io/simonjsuh/pen/ZEmrMyO) behind the page being flipped from the bottom right corner, but now I'm totally stuck on how to move onto the next step from here.

I'm looking for some basic guidance on how to replicate this page turning effect. What should I try next?

My Javascript code so far -

```
document.getElementById('book').addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    let book = document.getElementById('book').getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - book.right;
    let xAbsoluteValue = Math.abs(x);
    
    let y = e.clientY - book.bottom;
    let yAbsoluteValue = Math.abs(y);
    // console.log("From Right: " + xAbsoluteValue + "px | From Bottom: " + yAbsoluteValue + "px");

    // mid point between cursor and bottom right corner
    let xMidPoint = xAbsoluteValue/2;
    let yMidPoint = yAbsoluteValue/2;

    //update position of #midPoint div.
    let midPoint = document.getElementById('midPoint');
    midPoint.style.right = xMidPoint - 3 + 'px';
    midPoint.style.bottom = yMidPoint - 3 + 'px';

    // slope of line from bottom right corner to mouse = (change in y)/(change in x)
    let changeInY = y;
    let changeInX = -x;
    let slope = changeInY/changeInX;
    let slopeInverse = -changeInX/changeInY;

    // x and y coordinates of point intersecting between book outline and inverse slope
    let fromRightDistanceOfBookBottomAndInverseSlopeIntersectionPoint = 0;
    let fromBottomDistanceOfBookBottomAndInverseSlopeIntersectionPoint = 0;
    
    // y = mx + b      m is slope and b is y intersect. m = slopeInverse      y is y and x is -x
    b = y - slopeInverse*(-x);
    fromRightDistanceOfBookBottomAndInverseSlopeIntersectionPoint = ( - b)/slopeInverse;

    // draw line between midpoint and bottom intersect
    let perpendicularLine = document.getElementById('perpendicularLineInsideMidPoint');

    // convert slopeInverse into degrees
    degree = Math.atan(-slopeInverse)*180/Math.PI;

    perpendicularLine.style.transform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";

    document.getElementById('mouseCoordinates').innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <span>From Right: </span> ${xAbsoluteValue}px
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>From Bottom: </span> ${yAbsoluteValue}px
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>slope: </span> ${slope}
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>slope inverse: </span> ${slopeInverse}
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>degree: </span> ${degree}
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>b: </span> ${b}
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Intersect Bottom: </span> ${fromRightDistanceOfBookBottomAndInverseSlopeIntersectionPoint}
      </div>
    `;
  }
);
```

Comment: it's interesting how turnjs has portions of the page visible outside of the 'book' area during the page turn.